# Can't query multiple subject areas in OBIEE

Tags: oracle, weblogic12c, obiee

everyone. I am using OBIEE 12c and I faced a problem when trying to use two different subject areas in generating an analysis.

I started with creating the analysis based on one subject area. Then in Criteria tab, there is '>>' icon which contains 'Add/remove subject ares' link. Howerver, in my case it is not selectable. What can I do?

If there should be done any joins in repository level, how to do that? Thanks for help

Comment: I did some searching, and some sources say in order this link to be selectable, subject areas you want to add should be from the same BMM layer. Could that be the issue? Cause in my case all of my subject areas are from different BMM layers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add/remove SA only works for SAs built on the same Business Model.

Heterogeneous source queries from totally unrelated SAs can only be accessed via UNIONs within the same analysis.